# Git syncing two branches called "production" in two repos

Tags: git

I've seen similar questions about this, but none that give me confidence to risk mangling my git. I'm not a total noobie, but have never had the need to deal with two repos so I want to know the *right* way to do this.

I'm working on a project where we have one repo for staging (`SRV-S`) and another repo for production (`SRV-P`). Both have "production" branches that go live if pushed to, via Jenkins magic.

I'm not a git wiz so I maintain separate project folders for each repo. I make changes on `SRV-S` (staging repo, production branch) and once approved, manually copy those files over to my `SRV-P` folder (production repo, production branch). Then I cd into `SRVF-P` and git add, commit, push. Tedious.

Is there an easy way I can have be in the staging repo, on the branch named 'production', then pull a branch named 'production' from another repo, then push to either repo. i.e. that 'production' branch would exist in two repos with the same history.

Comment: Why two repositories?

Comment: This sounds like a recipe for disaster. There should be *one* repo, with a staging branch and a production branch. Push commits to the staging branch, and when it is working as it should, merge it into the production branch.

Comment: If there must be two repos, there is no reason for both to have staging and production branches. The production repository's live branch should track the  staging repository's live branch. Push to the staging repo, and when it is working, the production repo pulls and merges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your major problem is that the repos are not *really* tied, are they? Like, you have two separate repos, two branches with the same name... but they have *always* run in parallel, no common ancestor. If that's the case, you can still play with a single local repo where you will work and you have two remotes set up on it (srv-p, srv-s). Now.... I guess you will be mostly doing work against srv-s... and then *at some point* you decide that what you have in srv-s/production is what you would like to have on srv-p/production (content-wise, not history-wise).

The way to do that with the least effort and without having to move stuff around by hand is:

```
git checkout srv-s/production
# you would be on detached HEAD

# next step is where the magic happens:
# - move branch "pointer" to srv-p/production
# - keep our content as is, all differences between our working tree
#   and srv-p/production will be on index, ready to be committed
git reset --soft srv-p/production

# now we create a new revision so that the two branches have
# exactly the same content
git commit -m "A new version in srv-p/production"

# now we push into srv-p/production cause right now we are still
# on detached HEAD
# we actually haven't moved any branch either locally
# or on any of the two remotes
git push srv-p HEAD:production # send current HEAD to srv-p/production
```

I am doing this without any local branches, you could get the flow going with local branches as well.

Comment: So, I guess I would first have to cd into srv-s locally, and `git remote add srv-p git@github.com:srv-p.repo.url`, then do your steps? My worry is that `git reset --soft` will reset the production branch in the production repo (whose history I want unmolested). I think what I would like is to have two branches in srv-s (production and s-production). When production is ready, I merge it into s-production. Then in the srv-p repo, I add the srv-s remote, pull (fetch?) srv-s/s-production branch and manually merge it into srv-p/production with my IDE.

Comment: Well.... I don't know the details of where the repos are located.... I assumed for my response (like I said on the body of the answer) that you have a single repo that has the two repos you are talking about (the ones that jenkins is keeping an eye on) as remotes.... so no CDint into any of those two remotes. You would be pushing into them from another repo.

Comment: The comments from the other guys saying that you are not doing things properly? I would say that what you are doing is possible... but you would be better served by using a single repo with staging and production branches.... but my answer worked from your current situation with 2 repos.

Answer (score 1):

The core issue is that you have a bad versioning strategy. You should **not** be maintaining two repos.

Merge the repos into one and maintain a separate branch for production and staging. Then merge between the two branches.